# Python project setup broken

Tags: python, pip

I have project and It was working fine previously but when I switched to some other projects for some months and now when I'm trying to install the project again it is giving me below error.

I'm using Mac Mojave.
The error is too big so I cannot paste it but attaching images.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ImportError%3A+cannot+import+name+Feature+from+setuptools

Comment: This is a totally different error than before your edit. If you have another problem, open another question instead of editing a question that already has answers to the first problem.

Comment: Also, what did you try to do/install and which command(s) did you use to get this error?

Answer (score 0):

`from setuptools import Feature` does not work, because `Feature` was [removed](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/1979) from setuptools after being [deprecated in 2013](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/65). You can [pin an old setuptools version](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2017#issuecomment-655205448) or stop using it (see [this](https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe/pull/24/commits/b74cfd1f7ab5a82b2d0bf96f750998bc66324034) example).

1. Pin old version: In your requirements, explicitly list `setuptools==45` (or install it beforehand using something like `pip install setuptools==45`).
2. Stop using it: Instead of using `Feature`, use equivalent tools (depending on what you use `Feature` for). [Here](https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe/pull/24/commits/b74cfd1f7ab5a82b2d0bf96f750998bc66324034#diff-60f61ab7a8d1910d86d9fda2261620314edcae5894d5aaa236b821c7256badd7) is one example of removing `Feature` from the [markupsafe](https://github.com/pallets/markupsafe) project.

Comment: Do I have to do it manually? Isn't there any fixes for it?

Comment: If you are not the author, use `pip install setuptools==45` before installing the project. If you are the author, use `setuptools==45` as requirement to keep using an old version, or stop using `Feature` so you are safe to use current versions.

Answer (score 0):

This feature was removed intentionally in [46.0.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v46-0-0). You can downgrade to setuptools<46 to build/install the package.

for refrence->
https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v46-0-0